# Why Xdebug 3 log is empty?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so

xdebug.mode=debug

xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

I had set permissions 777 to xdebug.log file

I run

```
php7.4 index.php
```

PhpStorm listening is on.

[image]

[image]

Code does not stop on breakpoints when running from command line, so probably I need to check the log for info.

Comment: So you run `php7.4 index.php` outside of IDE? Not using "Debug" button on selected Run/Debug Configuration ("PHP Script" type) in PhpStorm? If that's the case .. then you still need to configure Xdebug -- either have `xdebug_break();` in your PHP code ... or have `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` in your php.ini (so Xdebug will try to debug the script right away). Right now Xdebug will still look for "debug me" trigger in your ENV,

Comment: @LazyOne yes, just from xubuntu terminal. And it works, thanks.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank for the tip, `start_with_request` works for me. But can you please explain why? I upgraded to xdebug3 and PhpStorm 2020.3.1. I configured it successfully for two of my vagrant apps. But the third was not successful. Looks like I missed something. Configuration seems to be correct. Where can I found more details on this?

Comment: @FreeLightman 1) Migrate Xdebug v2 to v3 (includes changes in logic): https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide 2) That particular option: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#start_with_request.

Comment: @FreeLightman When you debug a web page using Xdebug browser extension (or a [boormarklet](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/)) then it adds Xdebug cookie that got sent together with the request -- it acts as "debug me" flag. Another way is to add a GET/POST param to your URL (used when you click "Debug" in PhpStorm or you an use manually when needed. E.g.

Comment: @FreeLightman When debugging API requests from Postman or alike you can use any of those (Cookie is a bit more difficult/inconvenient to add but easier to manage (when swithing between Dev / Prod environments) while GET param -- easy to add .. but inconvenient to manage (part of the URL)).

Comment: @FreeLightman When debugging a CLI script (launch from IDE), PhpStorm adds all needed params. In PhpStorm case the "hidden" `XDEBUG_CONFIG` ENV variable does the trick. It's a bit undocumented .. but just presence of `XDEBUG_CONFIG` ENV variable will act as "debug me" flag.

Comment: @FreeLightman So .. if `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` then Xdebug will try to debug EVERY SINGLE REQUEST regardaless of "debug me" flag. If it has another value (e.g. `default` or `trigger`)  it will then be looking for that "debug me" flag (which can be a cookie/GEt param/ENV variable etc). How you have got your setup there is up to you. I may only say (for `start_with_request` value other than "yes": if you have it working in both PhpStorm and VSCode -- in PhpStorm it's a bit easier for CLI as it adds some stuff that you need to do manually in VSCode.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you for so detailed explanation. Now I know how to enable debugging for cli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @LazyOne comment, tried this way and it works - stops at breakpoints and log file gets recorded:

```
php7.4 -d xdebug.start_with_request=yes index.php
```

Comment: Stolen answer from @LazyOne comment. Not fair, not fair.

Comment: Are you joking ? :)

Comment: No he is not, you couldve asked if he would submit an answer instead of just copy pasting his solution and claiming the answer as your own.

Comment: @Maarten why do additional work and waste additional time? If he wants he can post his answer, there is no problem, he could post answer insntantly instead of comment

Comment: And if nobody will post, it will not be clear if solution worked or not.

Comment: It doesnt matter if it is additional work. It is nice to do additional work to make sure a person gets what he deserves.

Comment: Is this your opinion or are there such rules? For me it does not matter, he could write the asnwer and my can be deleted :) but he does not write so long.

Answer (score 1):

Here is configuration, that correctly works with **nginx + php-fpm** in **docker**, **xdebug3**, activation with **Chrome/Firefox extension**.

```
[Xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

More details about combinations of configuration for ***xdebug.mode*** and ***xdebug.start_with_request*** params, you can find [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#start_with_request#trigger). Also, when using the nginx web server, debugging may fail if the

> $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]

is not provided by PHP. To solve this, add a ***fastcgi*** parameter to the nginx configuration(e.g., ***/etc/nginx/conf.d/symfony.conf***):

```
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
```

or

```
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
```